# Inside a range how can I internally count up to 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Sort of like this:

```
for i in range(n):
    if i == first:
        x()
    if i == second:
        y()
    if i == third:
        z()
```

I just wish to recognise the first, second and third iterations in a loop till the range reaches it's limit.

Thank you

**Edit**

For each first, second, third iteration inside of the range I need to execute a different function.

```
i = 0 # x()
i = 1 # y()
i = 2 # z()
i = 3 # x()
i = 4 # y()
i = 5 # z()
i = 6 # x()
i = 7 # y()
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll go out on a limb and guess that you're looking for the modulus operator:

```
for i in range(10):
    print(i % 3 + 1)

# 1 2 3 1 2 3 ...
```

For your purposes:

```
for i in range(n):
    [x, y, z][i % 3]()
```

Or more verbose:

```
for i in range(n):
    if i % 3 == 0:
        x();
    elif i % 3 == 1:
        ...
```

Or if you don't actually have a `range`:

```
counter = 0;
while True:
    [x, y, z][counter % 3]()
    counter += 1
```

Or dead simple:

```
counter = 0
while True:
    [x, y, z][counter]()
    counter = counter % 3  # reset to 0 every 3rd iteration
```

Comment: I've updated my question, I think I threw everyone off with the fixed range of 10. n is infinite for my purposes, till conditions are no longer True.

Comment: So you want to do something *every 1st, 2nd, 3rd* iteration, or on *the 1st, 2nd, 3rd* iteration? Big difference. Also, doesn't `%` provide a solution? Have you thought about it? In what way doesn't it apply? It's entirely unclear how far off the mark I am with this answer unless you specifically reply to it.

Comment: I think I've covered every possibility for you now. Take you pick.

Comment: Thank you, yeah I think my approach was overcomplicated, just a simple while true + counter is all I needed

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(10):
    if i == 0:
        print ("1")
    if i == 1:
        print("2")
    if i == 2:
        print("3")
```